# How to call onclick and a href in the same time

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

```
  boilerPalte.activityStream = 
                            "<div class='socvid-aspect-ratio-container'>"+
                                "<div onclick='com.ivb.module.home.pics.showDialogBox(\"{%=nodeId%}\",\"{%=classNameId%}\")'>"+
                                    "<a href = {%=centerUrl%}>"+
                                    "<img src='{%=imageUrl%}'>"+
                                    "</a>"+
                                "</div>"+
                            "</div>";
```

I want that showDialogBox function be be executed when i click the div and in the same time the a href to work. In the code above the onclick does not work, only a href works.
I want an ajax request to occur (and presumably actually succeed) and then for the browser to go ahead and locate to the link specified in the anchor tag

Comment: Can you be using the onclick on anchor instead of on div??
Then you may be using <a href = {%=centerUrl%} onclick="...">
...
Your onclick will be executed first and then the href...

Else you can write a function which will be called on click which will in sequence call both the functions of onclick as well as anchor..

Comment: handle hyperlink `onclick` event only

Comment: What does `showDialogBox` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
com.ivb.module.home.pics.showDialogBox = function(nodeId, classNameId, obj) {

    // something ...

    var href = $(obj).find('a').data('href');
    makeAjaxRequest().success(function() {
        location.href = href;
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
 <div onclick='com.ivb.module.home.pics.showDialogBox(\"{%=nodeId%}\",\"{%=classNameId%}\", this)'>
     <a data-href={%=centerUrl%}>
         <img src='{%=imageUrl%}'>
     </a>
 </div>
```

With `data-href` instead of `href` you don't need to prevent default event on your link. If you want to use `href` make sure you `e.preventDefault` on this link.

Answer (score 2):

In onclick function lets say clickme, on successful completion of ajax request write down the location of the page you wanted to redirect.

for eg.

```
function clickme()
{
$.get("service",{data},function(){
 location.href="www.abc.com";
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

call a onclick from div and redirect to the particular page from function using location.href

```
boilerPalte.activityStream = 
                            "<div class='socvid-aspect-ratio-container'>"+
                                "<div onclick='return com.ivb.module.home.pics.showDialogBox(\"{%=nodeId%}\",\"{%=classNameId%}\",\"{%=centerUrl%}\")'>"+
                                    "<img src='{%=imageUrl%}'>"+
                                    "</div>"+
                            "</div>";
```

in showDialogBox use location.href

Answer (score 0):

For my knowledge you can just do the following.

```
<div href="your href here" onclick="and your function">
```

Or am i not correctly understanding your question?

Comment: Cant this be comment...How on earth `div` started getting `href` attr?
So nice to see..LOL

Comment: thanks for reply.but it wont work only ajax call work href does not work.

Comment: @sayali ok sorry misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Java Script :

```
function func_search()
                {

                        alert("Enter Search Criteria...");

                        document.location.href="search?srcstring=" + srchdata;  

                }
```

HTML :

```
<a onclick="func_search();"><img src="images/srch.png"  title="" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Out this!!
    [http://jsfiddle.net/Y4qsp/]

It may help you ! Give an id to your a tag , call onClick function on that id and call your function from the click function.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing that you ca do is something like (in jQuery):

```
<div style="cursor:pointer; width: 100%; background-color: red">
   <a href="http://google.com">Your link</a>
</div>
$("div").click(function(){
   window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;
});
```

`cursor:pointer` to get the right cursor when you are over the div.
In ajax environment you could get better result with:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
}).done(function() {
  // handle successfull operations
});
```

read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for details.